# Discarding rows containing empty string in CSV from uploading through SQL Loader control file

Tags: oracle12c, sql-loader, controlfile

I am trying to upload a CSV which may/may not contain empty value for a column in a row.
I want to discard the rows that contain empty value from uploading to the DB through SQL Loader.

How can this be handled in ctrl file:

I have tried below conditions in the ctl file :

```
when String_Value is not null

when String_Value <> ''
```

but the rows are still getting inserted

Comment: This can only mean the values are not the empty string in the CSV. Maybe a space, a newline or other control character?

Comment: @marekful: the values are definitely empty; the row in the csv for the column shows value like: ' "YYY","","XXX" ', so the middle column has empty value

Comment: Show us a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It works as you expect so you're doing something different in your control file, or are getting something different from what you've described, and we can't guess what.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using either `'<>'` or `'!='`.  I suspect the order of the clauses was incorrect for you.  Note `colc` (also the third column in the data file) matches the column name in the table.

```
load data 
infile 'c:\temp\x_test.dat'
TRUNCATE
into table x_test
when colc <> ''
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS 

(
    cola char,
    colb char,
    colc char,
    cold integer external
)
```